# SVG with multiple path

Tags: css, vue.js, svg

How do play with the different fill variables inside an svg ?

I am trying like this but I don't get any results :

```
<img class="icon-shop icon-colors" src="@/assets/icon-shop.svg"/>
...
<style>
.icon-colors {
  --color-default: #c13127;
  --color-dark: #ef5b49;
}
</style>
```

**icon-shop.svg**

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="..." fill="var(--color-default)"/><path d="..." fill="var(--color-dark)"/><path d="..." fill="var(--color-default)"/><g><path d="..." fill="var(--color-default)"/></g></svg>
```

Edit 1 :

When I try to use svg as a .vue file, I get a blank page and this console error :

```
Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/img/icon-shop.7de319ba.svg') is not a valid name.
```

edit 2 :
I am not sure how I should export the variable components

```
<template>
  <svg
    v-if="name === 'shop'"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  >
    <path
      d="M15.6 1.6H8.4c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v2.5h8.5V2.3c.1-.4-.2-.7-.6-.7z"
      fill="var(--color-default)"
    />

  </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["name", "var(--color-default)", "var(--color-black)"],
};
</script>
```

**Component Call**

```
<IconShopVue
      color-default="#c0ffee"
      color-dark="#c0ffee"
      class="w-8 h-8"
      name="shop"
    ></IconShopVue>
```

Comment: This could also be solved using [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) but I'd rather use those to toggle a theme or alike. Here, you're using some scoped class + CSS variables, I'd recommend using Vue props for that purpose, seems more adapted and easily customizable IMO.

Comment: @kissu he is using CSS Variables but they don't apply cross-document.

Comment: @RobertLongson yeah, on top of that the use-case seems a bit overkill here, especially since we can simply pass some Vue props. Having them defined in `:root` would be okay I guess, or it will still not be supported via the `img/src` import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### UPDATE on how to make this code functional

```html
<template>
  <svg
    v-if="name === 'shop'"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
  >
    <path
      d="M15.6 1.6H8.4c-.4 0-.7.3-.7.7v2.5h8.5V2.3c.1-.4-.2-.7-.6-.7z"
      :fill="colorDefault"
    />

  </svg>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["name", "colorDefault", "colorBlack"],
};
</script>
```

```html
<IconShopVue
  color-default="#c0ffee"
  color-dark="#c0ffee"
  class="w-8 h-8"
  name="shop"
></IconShopVue>
```

---

You should put your svg into a `.vue` file, copy your SVG code into the `template` section. Then, pass some props to your `.vue` component and interpolate the actual `default/dark` colors as you would do with any other kind of props.

```html
<my-cool-svg header-color="#c13127" outline-color="#ef5b49" fill-color="#c0ffee"></my-cool-svg>
```

This will provide a lot of flexibility overall VS working with a classic `.svg` file.

This is how the `.vue` should look like

```html
<template>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="..." :fill="headerColor"/>
    <path d="..." :fill="outlineColor"/>
    <path d="..." :fill="fillColor"/>
    <g>
      <path d="..." :fill="fillColor"/>
    </g>
  </svg>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['headerColor', 'outlineColor', 'fillColor']
}
</script>
```

Comment: When I put my svg in .vue then use it I get a blank page : Failed to execute 'createElement' on 'Document': The tag name provided ('/img/icon-shop.7de319ba.svg') is not a valid name.

Comment: You should import a `.vue` file, not an `.svg` one (in regards to your error).

Comment: it works thank you :) 
but my parameters aren't taken in consideration 

        <IconShopVue
          color-dark="red"
          color-default="blue"
          fill-color="yellow"
          class="w-8 h-8"
          name="shop"
        ></IconShopVue>

, it's all black

Comment: @GuillaumeAyad props are camelCase'd in the component. Feel free to edit your question with the latest changes for us to find out what is missing. Double check that your SVG is working if you hardcode those values too (for testing purposes).

Comment: Thank you for your help, see edit 2, the svg does change color when I change color inside svg

Comment: You're still trying to pass CSS variables rather than Vue props here. I'll edit my answer one more time.